# How do I deploy Apache-Airflow via uWSGI and nginx?

Tags: nginx, flask, airflow, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy airflow in a production environment on a server running nginx and uWSGI.

I've searched the web and found instructions on installing airflow behind a reverse proxy, but those instructions only have nginx config examples. However, due to the permissions, I can't change the nginx.conf itself and have to solve it via uswsgi.

My folder structure is:

```
project_folder
 |_airflow
   |_airflow.cfg
   |_webserver_config.py
   |_wsgi.py
 |_env
 |_start
 |_stop
 |_uwsgi.ini
```

My path/to/myproject/uwsgi.ini file is configured as follows:

```
[uwsgi]
master = True
http-socket = 127.0.0.1:9999
virtualenv = /path/to/myproject/env/
daemonize = /path/to/myproject/uwsgi.log
pidfile = /path/to/myproject/tmp/myapp.pid
workers = 2
threads = 2

# adjust the following to point to your project
wsgi-file = /path/to/myproject/airflow/wsgi.py
touch-reload = /path/to/myproject/airflow/wsgi.py
```

and currently the /path/to/myproject/airflow/wsgi.py looks as follows:

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b'Hello World!']
```

I'm assuming I have to somehow call the airflow flask app from the wsgi.py file (perhaps by also changing some reverse proxy fix configs, since I'm behind SSL), but I'm stuck; what do I have to configure?

Will this procedure then be identical for the workers and scheduler?

Comment: OK, Airflow includes its own backend web server (gunicorn). This means that I don't need to wire it up to uwsgi at all. 

That said, I'm now getting the warning to "Use a production WSGI server instead." for flask.  in production I'd like to run flask through WSGI for multi-threaded operations. Not sure how to do that yet.

Comment: Any progress on this?  I have a similar requirement.